# Realizar FIltro por rowIndex JSF

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

Solicito de su ayuda debio a que necesito realizar un filtro por medio del `rowIndex` del `dataTable`, la forma en al que obtengo el numero de la fila es el siguiente

```
value="#{testBean.dataTable.rowIndex + 1}"
```

y cuando lo voy a filtrar en la columa estoy usando

```
filterBy="#{testBean.dataTable.rowIndex + 1}"
```

y me genera error...?; el codigo completo es:

```
<rich:dataTable binding="#{testBean.dataTable }"
 var="datosItems" id="tablaDescripcion" rows="10" reRender="ds">

<rich:column width="40px" styleClass="rotuloLeft10"
  label="No. Item" 
  filterBy="#{testBean.dataTable.rowIndex + 1}" 
  filterEvent="onblur">
 <f:facet name="header">
  <h:outputText value="No. Item" />
 </f:facet>

 <h:outputText value="#{testBean.dataTable.rowIndex + 1 }"
  title="No. Item" styleClass="rotuloLeft11" />
</rich:column>

<rich:column width="40px" styleClass="rotuloLeft10"
 label="Referencia" filterBy="#{datosItems.caReferencia}" 
 filterEvent="onblur">
 <f:facet name="header">
  <h:outputText value="Referencia" />
 </f:facet>
 <h:outputText value="#{datosItems.caReferencia }"
  title="Referencia" styleClass="rotuloLeft11" />
</rich:column>
<f:facet name="footer">
 <rich:datascroller id="ds" renderIfSinglePage="false" />
</f:facet>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Error

```
Caused By: javax.el.ELException: //C:/proyectoDoble/web/build/classes/jsp/ninos/privado/procesos/listaNinos.jsp @1212,33 filterBy="#{testBean.dataTable.rowIndex + 1 }": java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:76)
at org.richfaces.model.impl.expressive.ValueBindingExpression.evaluate(ValueBindingExpression.java:79)
at org.richfaces.model.impl.expressive.ObjectWrapperFactory.wrapObject(ObjectWrapperFactory.java:209)
at org.richfaces.model.ModifiableModel$RowKeyWrapperFactory.wrapObject(ModifiableModel.java:75)
at org.richfaces.model.impl.expressive.ObjectWrapperFactory$2.convert(ObjectWrapperFactory.java:190)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.String.indexOf(String.java:1521)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkName(ClassLoader.java:776)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:948)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:292)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:296)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de JSF y RichFaces estás usando?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza `JSF 1.2` y `Richfaces 3.3.3`

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar el error que te da?

Comment: @hecnabae listo ya ingrese el error que esta generando